# Catalogsearch sidebar navigation not showing only for specific query string

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, catalogsearch

In my magento store I am facing a very weird case, in `catalogsearch/result` page sidebar navigation appearing correctly for all query string but for a **specific** query string it is not appearing.

When I debug it I found that for this search `$this->canShowBlock()` function in `catalog/layer/view.phtml` file return false.

When I try to `log something` inside this function in `Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php` as :

```
public function canShowBlock()
{
        Mage::log(print_r('hello', 1), null, 'debug.log');
        return $this->canShowOptions() || count($this->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters());
}
```

It is not print anything in `debug.log` file only for **specific** query search, but for other all query string this function print `hello` in `debug.log` file.

What is the problem here?

Comment: For that specific  query canShowBlock does not called

Comment: I know, but my question is why this is happening?

Comment: Can I use  `$this->canShowOptions() || count($this->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters())` in if condition in `catalog/layer/view.phtml` in place of `$this->canShowBlock()`? Is it a right way?